# How to run javascript and reload DIV containers every minute (timer)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, timer

I need to run the function **createChartControl** every minute. Each time the function is executed, the content of the DIV container **GanttDiv** should be updated. The problem is that the function **createChartControl** is executed only once. How to correctly add the timer?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function createChartControl(htmlDiv1)
{
    // ...
}
(function(){
    createChartControl('GanttDiv');
})();
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#GanttDiv").(function(){ 
        createChartControl('GanttDiv');
    })();
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $('#GanttDiv').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).(function(){ 
                createChartControl('GanttDiv');
            })().fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 60000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>

<div style="width:100%; height:350px; position:relative" id="GanttDiv" class="GanttDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are running it once a minute with your setInterval call. Are you getting any errors? Are you sure it's not running? Have you tried debugging with the developer's console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setInterval` seems to be correct but you're having an error in the first execution. Try this:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $('#GanttDiv').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        createChartControl('GanttDiv');
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
}, 60000);
```

Also if you're already passing the id to the `createChartControl` function, you don't need to do this (that, with an unmodified jQuery also it's not valid):

```
$("#GanttDiv").(function(){ 
    createChartControl('GanttDiv');
})();
```

You could just do

```
createChartControl('GanttDiv');
```